# How to get multiple user remote access for AWS Windows instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to get remote control access (RDP) for simultaneous multiple users on a Windows Server on AWS instance? 
What are the charges if it incurs any?

Answer (score 9):

You can create as many users as you like (within Windows limitations), but to have more than two RDP sessions on the same time you have to buy your own license, AWS does not provide it.

> If you need more than two simultaneous remote connections, you must
>   purchase a Remote Desktop Services (RDS) license. [(Source at AWS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html?tag=duckduckgo-ffab-20#connect-rdp)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, adding new users to Windows Server would have to be done the same way new users are added to Linux Instances -> through userdata or cloud-init part, programatically. 
For Windows that would be a powershell command, something like this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-AD-UserGroup-to-RDP-c17b24a4

As for charges, I am not aware of additional charges, but not a windows expert here.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that we can create 2 users for free in a Windows instance. So, I created a new user from the Control Panel of Windows server instance and used this new user name and password to login for the second user and it worked. I've not tried with even more users. I think that would incur cost. But not sure.